# Gradle build failing to download s3 maven Artifacts when using AWS SSO

Tags: maven, gradle, amazon-s3

Our private java Artifacts are hosted on AWS S3.
Our organisation moved from AWS access_key/secret_key set up to AWS SSO for security reasons, since then local builds are failing due to S3 access denied error. There is no issue with the production environment.

1. aws configure sso setup done for default profile. tested as well.
2. build.gradle.kts has

```
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven {
      url = uri("https://repos.spring.io/plugins-release")
    }


    maven {
      url = uri("s3://bucket-name/releases")
      authentication {
        create<AwsImAuthentication>("awsIm")
      }
    }

  }
```

3. Gradle version is 7.6.

Tried upgrading Gradle version to 8.5, did not help